# Unable to connect to servers in different VPCs using pvt. IPs thru SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, cloud, subnet, vpc

I've created two VPCs:

- VPC1 - 10.0.0.0/16, one subnet 10.0.0.0/24
- VPC2 - 10.1.0.0/27, subnets 10.0.0.0/28, 10.0.0.16/28.

I created three instances - one in VPC1 and two in VPC2. I was told to ping to servers associated with VPC1 from VPC2 and vice versa using SSH port 22 only. After establishing a peering network, I tried to ping as told but I am not able to do it. I am not able to get response packets even when I ping between the two instances in same VPC.

I am not sure what are the correct CIDR ranges in Security groups and Routing tables.

Comment: This looks like question for superuser for now. Where is your code / config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear so I'll try to make sure I understand.

You tried to connect 2 instances between different VPCs.
You need to answer to yourself - will they be accessible via **public or private IP addresses**?
As you mention 'peering network' I assume you tried to setup a **VPC peering** between 2 VPCs. This is only needed if you intend to connect via **internal** IP addresses.

For this to work you need:

1. VPC peering - this what you already established
2. Proper **route table** - that will allow instances from VPC1 to reach VPC2
3. Proper **Network ACL** configuration - that will not block traffic from VPC1 and VPC2. Note that NACL are stateless so the return traffic needs to be explicitly allowed.
4. Proper **Security Groups** configuration - mostly allowing **inbound** access in the desired ports. You mentioned SSH so TCP 22 needs to be open. 
   Note that because of the VPC peering you can now address the SG from VPC1 in the inbound rules of the instance in VPC2.

Regarding **outbound rules** - 
For now I suggest to go with the default allow all outbound traffic for ease of setup.

Note: In your tests you tried to ping between the servers. Ping is using the ICMP protocol, so if you only allows TCP22 - this will not work.

Your method to progress would be to first make sure 2 instances in the same VPC can communicate in the desired port, and then move to intra-vpc connectivity.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm from a non-IT background, so I do not know many fundamental concepts. I'm learning about cloud technologies. Could you suggest books and resources/tutorials to get thorough knowledge on cloud services(AWS) and related topics (like IP addressing, subnetting, networking, protocols, ports etc.).